# Is it possible to partially delete data using Data Retention in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

With the documentation I have read on Exact Target Data Retention Policy, it seems we can either delete the entire DE at a fixed time/after specific intervals or we can delete ALL DATA at a fixed time/after specific intervals.

Is it possible to delete partial data (data older than 6 months) and not ALL DATA or data extension using Data Retention policy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option for "Individual Records" which will only delete partial data based on the age provided.

[image: UI Example of Individual Records option]